# Performance Issues? (First time install Ubuntu 20.04.3)

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, performance

***Laptop Specs***

- Model: Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 2
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
- GPU: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Max-Q 4GB GDDR5
- RAM: 16GB 2666 MHz
- Storage: 500GB SSD

So I decided to go ahead and install ubuntu after using it for an assignment I had to do for a class--virtualmachine. I finished the install and after a couple hours and installing some apps--Discord, Google Chrome--I noticed that it seems to run a bit more sluggish (opening apps, discord text channels scrolling slowly, and discord server list scrolling slowly). Also an application froze to where I had to make a kill command to terminate it, and in general the file management app feels slower as opposed to when I used windows 10 file explorer. Even just now looking up the specs for my laptop in settings it took a 2 second pause before it would load the "About" tab. A problem I'm trying to solve right now is Google Chrome consistently crashing, like as in I can't use the browser for longer than 3 minutes--if even that.

Is there some quirks or modifications I have to make for Linux to be great? Any suggestions? I really like the OS overall and installing things seem so hassle free it's what made me like it so much.

Comment: With so much RAM and SSD, this lag should not happen. Try changing the NVIDIA driver (in `additional drivers`), and check if the issue persists. https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: Watch for processor power and/or temperature limit throttling. It might be throttling down too far, if settings are not right. Suggest using turbostat (linux-tools-common package) to monitor: `sudo /home/doug/temp-k-git/linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 6`

Comment: I'm unsure on how to use this command you posted? Should it be a throttling issue how would I get it solved though?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is changing to the proprietary nvidia drivers. You can do this by opening the application menu >> Additional Drivers >> select the top option for the newest nvidia driver.

Nouveau is the open source driver for nvidia that comes preinstalled with ubuntu and many other distros. It is a backwards engineered version of the proprietary drivers and tends to work poorly on higher end and newer cards.

Comment: Thank you on the graphic driver tip it kept my Google Chrome from crashing now. My only other problem is that it still feels slower than when it used to run on windows. Would there be anything else for me to check? Discord is actually so much noticeably slower (regardless of turning hardware accel on or off)

Comment: @MG0310 Do you mean it takes time to load the messages? Or do you mean that the applications take too long to open?

Comment: @Arashk Applications typically load fine, except for firefox which takes about 2 seconds, and then discord the entire app lags whenever I'm scrolling through my server list or the text channels. In general though, the OS seems laggy compared to windows. The animations struggle and opening an app seems to take a heavy hit to the system as listening to music the music would often chop out whenever I opened an app (mostly Discord but other apps as well). I was told to just reinstall the OS but unless other suggestions are thrown at me.

Comment: @MG0310 I have a lenovo Z50-70 so because of how old it is, every os has a bit of lag. Therefore, I can't really say I can confirm that. But I do have to say ubuntu is buggy and not the fastest. It could be ubuntu's fault for being heavy, or it could be a bad installation.